# Espresso UI Test Cancelled with no error message

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

Here is the problem when I run my UI test.
[image]

But the ExampleInstrumentedTest is working.

This is my test file, I already comment out everything, leaving an empty function

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class ExploreFragmentTest {

    @get: Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun test_isSearchButtonDisplayed() {
        //onView(withId(R.id.btn_search)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

Here is my dependency in app/gradle

```
    // AndroidX Test - Instrumented testing
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0'
```

#### how to see the actual error message???

#### Can we do better on the error feedback?

Comment: It happens here too. Did you discover what it is?

Comment: this mean the app crashed while running the test. In my case was segment analytics trying to make network call in the test environment.
Poor error message.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. My case was the same as yours. Could just find out after looking at crashlytics.

Comment: This answer fixed the issue for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/77271279/1441731

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same error.

I used adb and logcat to view the logs: `adb logcat`

I found this error in my logs:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerDefaultInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite;)V in class Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageLite; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite' appears in /data/app/~~BuZ1RxiHRJybZNpyUcjGIw==/-xuI8WeeYUojtsn-ncVI-aw==/base.apk)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.perf.v1.ApplicationInfo.<clinit>(ApplicationInfo.java:1085)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.perf.v1.ApplicationInfo.newBuilder(ApplicationInfo.java:533)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.perf.transport.TransportManager.finishInitialization(TransportManager.java:226)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.perf.transport.TransportManager.syncInit(TransportManager.java:220)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.perf.transport.TransportManager.$r8$lambda$LuAwHBxy50Yf-ziHqcD54KjEPtk(Unknown Source:0)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.perf.transport.TransportManager$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:2)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
01-30 08:23:34.286  5932  6012 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

To fix that, I excluded `protobuf-lite` from `androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0` in my `build.gradle` file:

```
androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0") {
    exclude module: "protobuf-lite"
}
```

And now my test works!

Comment: You have also to exclude `protobuf-lite` from `androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.4.0`

Comment: This solution worked for a while, and now it's happening again :/

Answer (score 6):

for me this was caused by using an x86 emulator.  when I switched to x86_64 the problem stopped for APIs 30 and below; however, I still have this issue using API 31.