# Android Espresso test case cancelled

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am executing the following Espresso code. This code is working fine.

```
import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EspressoTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void view_isCorrect() {
        onView(withText("Cash less")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

But ActivityTestRule is deprecated. Instead of this I am trying to use `ActivityScenarioRule`. But the same code using of ActivityScenarioRule is showing Test Cancelled.

After modify the code will will look like following.

```
import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EspressoTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> activityScenarioRule = new ActivityScenarioRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void view_isCorrect() {
        onView(withText("Cash less")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

[image: Error image]

I am using the following dependency in Gradle.

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
```

And also included `testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'` in the default block.

I tried with updating/downgrading the version. Tried another versions too. And also I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68976841/espresso-ui-test-cancelled-with-no-error-message).

But no luck. How can I resolve this issue?

I am setting compileSdkVersion to 33.

Comment: No @GobinathNataraj.. I done with ActivityTestRule..

Comment: Did you check the logs in the output window (which should show when you click on the test in the Run tab)?